# Make Flexbox overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a `div` with flexbox display and overflow hidden and it contains three other divs inside so it hides half of the third div here is my code:

```html
<div style="display: flex; height: 50px; width: 50px">
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 20px; background:blue"></div>
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 20px; background:red"></div>
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 20px; background: green"></div>
</div>
```

If it doesn't work with flexbox please suggest an alternative approach.
And thank you

Comment: It will work for sure. Please verify your code.

Comment: overflow:hidden is missing on the parent, then flex-shrink:0; is missing on the children ;) .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it worked i didn't know about this flex-shrink thanks